# atomのcssのコメントにつて

Tags: css, atom-editor, 文字化け

cssをatomで記述しています。コードがわかりやすいようにコメントを多用していたのですが今日atomを開いてみると

```
/*ã‚°ãƒ©ãƒ•ã®ä¸­å¤®å¯„ã›*/
```

のように文字化けしていました。どなたか直す方法をご存知の方教えて頂けると助かります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

文字コードの設定が何かしらの理由で変わったのではないかと推測されます。

ウィンドウ右下の表示から手動で文字コードを変えて上手く表示されるものを探すか、[auto-encoding](https://atom.io/packages/auto-encoding) などの自動検出パッケージをインストールして文字コードを自動変更させてください。

また、Atom のデフォルト設定で文字化けするということは、その CSS ファイルが UTF-8 以外の文字コードで保存されているのではないかと思います。現代的にはウェブ用のファイルの文字コードは Unicode 系に統一するのが良いと思います。

Answer (score 0):

cssファイルはAtomエディタのみで使われるわけではなく、最終的にはWebブラウザーに読み込むものではないでしょうか？ Atomエディタで文字化けするのであれば、Webブラウザーでも正しく解釈できない可能性があります。また、コメントだけでなく、`メイリオ` などのように日本語を含んだフォント名なども同時に化けている可能性もあります。

nekketsuuuさんの提案の一つauto-encodingなどの自動検出パッケージを使用した場合、Atomエディタ上でのみ問題が解決し、Webブラウザーは引き続き文字化けし正しく解釈できない可能性が出てきますので、おすすめできません。

CSSでは[@charset](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/@charset)の設定もできますがBOMありエンコーディングまたはUTF-8を使用することをお勧めします。